# How to encode a 8 byte block using only digits (numeric characters)?

Tags: language-agnostic, encoding

I need to encode streams of 8 byte such that encoded stream has only digits (zero to nine) in them. Are their any standard encoding mechanism for doing this? If there are multiple ways to do it, which one is efficient in terms of length of encoded string (shorter is better)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treat the 8 bytes as a 64-bit unsigned integer and convert it to decimal and pad it to the left with zeroes. That should make for the shortest possible string, as it utilizes all available digits in all positions except the starting one.

If your data is not uniformly distributed there are other alternatives, looking into Huffman-coding so that the most commonly data patterns can be represented by shorter strings. One way is to use the first digit to encode the length of the string. All numbers except 1 in the first position can be treated as a length specifier. That way the maximum length of 20 digits will never be exceeded. (The 20th digit can only be 0 or 1, the highest 64-bit number is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.) The exact interpretation mapping of the other digits into lengths should be based on the distribution of your patterns. If you have 10 patterns which are occuring VERY often you could e.g. reserv "0" to mean that one  digit represents a complete sequence.

Any such more complicated encoding will however introduce the need for more complex packing/unpacking code and maybe even lookup tables, so it might not be worth the effort.

Comment: But it will also be variable length, which requires a delimiter between blocks in the stream, which would be....? (Since all ten digits have been used.) :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've corrected and extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Living in binary world makes you alien to decimal world after some time. :)

Comment: Your first suggestion will *always* require 20 digits per 8-byte value, which doesn't seem to address the OP's length request (unless most of his values really are above 10,000,000,000,000,000,000).

Comment: As I understand variable length was suggested also in this answer. For example
"0xx" = x, "1xxxx" = x + 100, ..., "8xx..." (18 digits) = x + 10**16
so 8999999999999999999 = 1009999999999999999 ... "9xxx" (20 digits)

Comment: @ony: Right. As I said, *"Your **first** suggestion..."* The second half of the second suggestion might have legs, though I'd like to see it expanded/developed further. You don't have five bits to work with, although you do have some *values* to work with that may well pan out.

Comment: @TJ You're right about bits vs values. I've updated and tried to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the efficiency question will depend a *lot* on the typical range of values in the 8-byte blocks. Consider Unicode's UTF-8 and UTF-16. UTF-8 is very efficient for encoding texts written primarily in western scripts, because most characters in those scripts are in the range 0x00 to 0x7F that UTF-8 can store in a single byte. But it's not very efficient for encoding texts written primarily in eastern scripts; UTF-16 or UTF-32 is a better choice there.

If you have a read up on [the various UTFs](http://www.unicode.org/faq/), they may inspire a solution. Fundamentally they work by doing things like allowing a lot of values to be directly encoded in a byte, but then having a flag (the high-order bit, I think it is, in the case of UTF-8's first byte) indicating that that byte doesn't tell the whole story and the next byte (or two, or three, or four) is/are required. The starting point is a byte for UTF-8, a word for UTF-16, but the concepts are similar.

Now, you're working with a *dramatically* smaller range of values (0-9 rather than 0-255), and obviously I'm not recommending trying to directly use UTF, just the concept. For instance, say most of your values (directly or with some massaging) are less than 9000, quite a few are less than 9000000, and only rare values take you out beyond that. You might take the UTF approach and say that blocks (your 8-byte values) are divided into four-digit segments, and you'll always have at least one segment (four digits) per encoded block. If the first segment's value (aaaa) is between 0000 and 8999 (inclusive), it's a "terminal" segment — that's the actual value. But if it's 9aaa, that means there's a second segment and you should look at aaabbbb (bbbb being the next segment's value). If *that* value is between 0000000 and 8999999 (inclusive), it's a terminal; but if it's 9aabbbb, it means look at aabbbbcccc (cccc being the next segment); etc. I *think* that would give us this:

```
00000000000000000000-00000000000000008999 ->  4 digits (xxxx)
00000000000000009000-00000000000008999999 ->  8 digits (9xxxxxxx)
00000000000009000000-00000000008999999999 -> 12 digits (99xxxxxxxxxx)
00000000009000000000-00000008999999999999 -> 16 digits (999xxxxxxxxxxxxx)
00000009000000000000-00008999999999999999 -> 20 digits (9999xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
00009000000000000000-08999999999999999999 -> 24 digits (99999xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
09000000000000000000-18446744073709551615 -> 28 digits (999999xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
Or special case, just use 26 digits for the last one:  (999999xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
```

There your best case is four digits and worst is 28 or 26, depending on whether you want to special-case the last segement in the block. A lot better (probably) than using 20 digits for each block.

Now, that's completely off-the-cuff and probably not as efficient as it could be, but you get the idea. It's very easy to deserialize, and probably not that hard to serialize.

You can see why I started with the comment about what your typical values are. If they're typically above 10,000,000,000,000,000,000, the above is not an efficient way to encode them directly. But similar techniques can be used if your typical values are at the high end rather than the low, by massaging the value a bit before encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The result that has the shortest length is to convert it to decimal directly. This leads to the highest value being `18446744073709551615`, but conversion can be difficult without arbitrary length integer capability.

The next longest is to convert it to octal as one chunk. This results in a maximum length of 22, with a value of `1777777777777777777777`. This requires only shifts to convert, and can be handled easily enough.

The next longest is to convert it to either octal or decimal bytewise. This results in a length of 24, with 8 repetitions of `377` or `255` respectively. Converting back and forth is trivial, and is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As for the first option being difficult without arbitrary length integer capability, it is not really an issue. You can split the block in 4 byte integers, convert them to decimal individually and then concatenate them. Since a 4 byte unsigned value takes maximum 10 digits, we still have 20 digits for 8 byte block. What do you think?

Comment: That's certainly a workable solution, as is breaking it up into 4 2-byte blocks of 5 digits each.

Comment: With the 2 times 4 byte solution you need to watch for the boundaries. Is 111 a 1 in the upper bytes and a 11 in the lower bytes or vice versa or what? So you need to always use exactly 20 digits with this method.